# webfont does not apear without www

Tags: css, .htaccess, webfonts

I have tried to find the answer everywhere. I have a sing website [www.hugeone.co.uk](http://www.hugeone.co.uk). When the address is like in this link (with www.) everything is ok. But if I type only hugeone.co.uk webfonts do not appear, and I get the message:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at
>   http://www.hugeone.co.uk/includes/templates/huheone/css/fonts/dirtyheadline-webfont.woff.
>   This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or
>   enabling CORS.

my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Don't rewrite any URIs ending with a file extension (ending with .[xxxxx])
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-z]{2,5}$ [NC]
# Don't rewrite any URIs for some, popular specific file format extensions,
#   which are not covered by main file extension condition above
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(mp3|mp4|h264)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/editors/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite .settings directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.settings/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite ajax_bin directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ajax_bin/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite artwork directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/artwork/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite bigdump directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bigdump/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite bmz_cache directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bmz_cache/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite catal directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catal/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite catdescr directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/catdescr/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite ebay directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ebay/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite feed directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feed/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite fonts directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fonts/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite ftp-uploads directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ftp\-uploads/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite harvest directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/harvest/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite invoices directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/invoices/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite jobs directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/jobs/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite logo directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/logo/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite londynek directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/londynek/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite phpmyadmin directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite populate directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/populate/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite temp directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/temp/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite test directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/test/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite uploads directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/uploads/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite very_secret directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/very_secret/ [NC]
# Don't rewrite video directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/video/ [NC]
# Handle all other URIs using Zen Cart (its index.php)
RewriteRule .* index.php [QSA,L]

## END CEON URI MAPPING REWRITE RULE

#WEBFONTS

AddType font/ttf .ttf
AddType font/eot .eot
AddType font/otf .otf
AddType font/woff .woff

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I do not know what I can do more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If redirecting all the non-`WWW` requests to `WWW` is an option you could do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hugeone\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.hugeone.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Add that right below:

```
RewriteEngine On
# optional you might not have the below in your file.
RewriteBase /
```

In your `.htaccess` file.

An alternative to the above would be to enable CORS using your `.htaccess` for webfonts it would be like this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff|font.css|css)$">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

***As a side note its better if your don't use both `WWW` and non-`WWW` as Google for instance doesn't like seeing both.***

Comment: Hi I have accepted it but I had to wait before I was allowed to do it. I had the Access-control.. part in my .htaccess but it did not work. I use only www with google but users cant put the url without the www.

Comment: @PiotrJankowski yes, there is a wait time when the question is very recent, thanks, glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Both the url and  value should be same.

Two solutions are possible in this case.

1. Redirecting all the non-www request to www
2. Changing the base href value based on the url.