# Openlayers 3 does not display icons in FireFox or Chrome

Tags: kml, openlayers-3

I have a problem displaying icons on an OpenLayers map when viewing the map in FireFox and Chrome. To isolate this behavior I created an Openlayers 3 script that displays icons on a map by loading data from a KML file. The script I'm using is based upon this Openlayers example:

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/examples/kml.html

Modifications to this script include reference my KML source file and the type of map to display.

Icons display properly when the kml icon reference url points to Google like:

```
<Icon>
  <href>http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png</href>
</Icon>
```

But when I change the icon reference to the same icon located on my server, the icon is not visible in Chrome or FireFox.

```
<Icon>
  <href>http://www.photoradius.com/data/assets/icons/mm_20_brown.png</href>
</Icon>
```

In all of my test cases, the icons display as expected in IE.

For reference, here are example files:

1) Icons display as expected in all browsers:
http://photoradius.com/debugol3/kml_google.htm
icon reference in kml file:
http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png

2) Icons do NOT display in Chrome or FireFox (but do in IE)
http://photoradius.com/debugol3/kml_local.htm
icon reference in kml file:
http://www.photoradius.com/debugol3/icons/mm_20_brown.png

So the only difference in the two examples I've created is the location of the icon. If the icon is located on the Google server, it is plotted in all browsers. If it resides on my server, only IE plots the icons.

Any advice will be welcome.
Regards.

Comment: Did you check your console message? `Image from origin 'http://www.photoradius.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://photoradius.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: I don't see Cross-Origin resource. Why would it make a difference if the icon is coming from Google or resides on my server?

Comment: If you want to run locally, use localhost, if not, configure your web server to allow CORS.

Comment: I don't understand the need for a Cross-Origin resource when all the resources, css, js, icon png's reside on the same shared hosting environment.

Comment: The images in the KML are linking to `http://www.photoradius.com/...` but you are calling the site with `http://photoradius.com/...` (without the `www`). This question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710015/webfont-does-not-apear-without-www

Comment: I've changed all the icon references to be relative to the html document, (i.e., icons/forest.png) and the icons still do not appear. Tested files on three shared hosting environments, none of which have an active .htaccess file, with the same result. Icons referenced locally do not appear on map.